# Magnetic fileds

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

I am trying to circulate particles that are dispersed in water by using a magnetic field. Would it help conduct the magnetic field better if graphene or copper particles were dispersed into the solution as well? This is opposed to trying to increase the power needed to increase the magnetic field.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do: move the fluid, move the particles without moving any fluid, redistribute the particles in some arrangement, randomize the particles? What do you mean "conduct the magnetic field?"

Answer (score 0):

Graphene, Copper are Diamagnetic - have lower permeability than free space.

Copper's Diamagnetic constant is close to water so would have little effect.

Graphene's stronger Diamagnetism would exclude magnetic field from the particles depending on orientation.
With the orientation effect and practical solid suspension volume fraction in water the increase in mag field in the water would be small.

Practically only ferromagnetic material will make a difference - see "ferrofluid" and then $\mu_r$ will be at best single digit.

And the increase in fluid path permeability will be less useful at higher fields as the magnetic particles saturate at relatively low field compared to what is easily achieved in modern NbFe magnets.

You should probably be asking about magnet, "magnetic circuit" design, flux concentrating high Bmax pole pieces...